# Difference between Permutation and Combination.

Tags: combinatorics

I know this question has been asked a ton of times. So today someone have me a simple to make a 4 digit number out of 4 digits. The answer was obviously $4!$. I even showed him the numbers possible.

Then he asked me difference between permutation and combination, I gave him the same old plain answer.

Then he showed me how he did this question-
$$
C^4_1 \ C^3_1 \ C^2_1 \ C^1_1 
\\
\_\_\_ \ \_\_\_  \ \_\_\_ \ \_\_\_
$$
He said we can select 1 element out of 4 elements for the first place, for the second place 1 out of 3 and so on...

And finally we would multiply all of them to get the answer $24$.
Then he showed me his second approach-
$$
P^4_1 \ P^3_1 \ P^2_1 \ P^1_1 
\\
\_\_\_ \ \_\_\_  \ \_\_\_ \ \_\_\_
$$
He said we would select the element and permutate it, 1 out of 4, 1 out of 3 and so on...

He multiplied all the values and again the answer came out to be same (24) and now asked me the difference between permutation and combination.

I was confused by what he did and couldn't figure out why the answers were same. I hope someone with more clarity about this can help.

Comment: This is not clear.  Presumably, for the first problem, the order matters.  The number $1234$ is not the same as the number $4321$.  Now, if you ignore the order, these two collections would be the same.  I think it all comes down to stating clearly what it is you are trying to count.

Comment: To stress:  the distinction between permutation and combination is that in the former the order matters, in the latter it does not.

Comment: @lulu It just says to count 4 digit numbers when you are given 4 digits, no repetition. Just find the no. of 4 digit numbers which can be made from a,b,c,d.

Comment: Sure, so that's $4!$ just as you said (ignoring things like first digit $0$ and so on).  No problem there at all.  But after that you appear to be trying to compute something else, and I have no idea what that might be.

Comment: To stress:  your question is extremely vague.  Perhaps you are just remarking that, if you are choosing one element out of some collection, order is obviously not relevant (there is only one way to order one thing).  Could that be your question?

Comment: @lulu I think you made a very good point that order does not matter for one element that's why we are getting same answers which is obvious.